# Error in android gradle file using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When I was building the app, I received these error messages. I tried my best but I couldn't find a good solution. Please help me. I'm posting my error log below.

```
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/libraries/mapsplatform/secrets-gradle-plugin/secrets-gradle-plugin/1.3.0/secrets-gradle-plugin-1.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/libraries/mapsplatform/secrets-gradle-plugin/secrets-gradle-plugin/1.3.0/secrets-gradle-plugin-1.3.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: anyone help me please

Comment: Why are you using gradle 4.1? Go to your gradle-wrapper.properties file and change the URL to match latest version. Replace `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1.0-bin.zip` with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2.0-bin.zip` and in build.gradle, replace `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0`

Comment: when I use this then it shows this error


[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-7.2.0-bin.zip
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1896)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)